# Ejemplos de la integral de Jackson (Examples of Jackson's Integral)

Tags: calculus, quantum-calculus

**Original question in Spanish**

La integral de Jackson está definida en el cálculo cuántico, y quisiera que alguien me ayudara a la explicación de un ejemplo de este estilo de integrales. Gracias

---

**Added**

**Translation:**

The [Jackson integral](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jackson_integral) is defined in [quantum calculus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_calculus), and I would like for someone to help me with an explanation of an example of this style of integral. Thanks

Comment: This site is _English_ only.

Comment: That's not accurate, @vonbrand. Many askers along time have been encouraged to write down their questions in their own language if they have some problem understanding english, hoping someone understands them *and the problem* and can help them. I know spanish, for example, yet I've no idea what that integral could possibly be...

Comment: Maybe http://www.sajm.com.nu/sajm2012_2_5_1sulaiman.pdf and 
http://arxiv.org/pdf/math-ph/0610079.pdf

Comment: see http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0302032 and the book Quantum Calculus by V. Kac and P. Cheung (2002). Jackson's articles were in 1904 and 1910.

Comment: @Amzoti, is it possible the phrase "calculo cuantico" refers to "Quantum Calculus," as in the book by Victor Kac?

Comment: @Amzoti, after going quickly through the arXiv piece I link by Kac and De Sole, that has got to be it. But let me look at your links for a minute....Alright, the Feyn-Jackson integral is a more elaborate item. What is clear is that the Kac book is a good idea.

Comment: @Amzoti, I note your articles include the Kac/Cheung book in the references, also the Kac De Sole article. So my guess would be that your only responsibility is to edit a note after your translation saying "it might also mean quantum calculus," keep your comments here as they are constructive, and wait on clarification from lizeth.

Comment: http://www.springer.com/mathematics/analysis/book/978-0-387-95341-0

Comment: @WillJagy: noted in update. Thanks for cross-verifying - regards.

Comment: @Amzoti, I corrected your edit a bit, since I agree with Will that the correct translation of "cálculo cuántico" should be "quantum calculus". I also added a couple of links to the corresponding Wikipedia articles.

Comment: @AdriánBarquero: thank you - this is what I truly love about MSE, a community of people helping to provide the best solutions and guidance! Regards

Answer (score 2):

It appears the responsible thing to do is to recommend the book by [KAC and CHEUNG](http://www.springer.com/mathematics/analysis/book/978-0-387-95341-0) and the papers that Amzoti and I found online, in comments. The book is a reference in all the articles, so I think it's a winner. The article I found is [KAC DE SOLE](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0302032). Meanwhile, it appears the Jackson integral is rather simpler than the later Feynman-Jackson integral. Indeed, the two of them have a million articles together, see [ALBERTO DE SOLE](http://arxiv.org/find/math/1/au%3a+Sole_A/0/1/0/all/0/1)

Comment: until we hear anything further, this is about as good as it will get! +1 Regards

Comment: @Amzoti, maybe you're right. I just got caught up in the thing.

Comment: Just for curiosity: why the caps?

Comment: @MatemáticosChibchas, not entirely  sure, although it seems that there was a bit of difficulty communicating with the person asking, so i believe I added capital letters as a way of drawing attention. I can't say it made any difference, the OP posted nothing whatsoever after the initial question. If someone has trouble with English but comes back and puts some effort into communicating, they will probably get some useful information.